# What is the area of the closed curve?

Tags: graphing-functions, polar-coordinates, area

The graph of the polar graph $r=\dfrac{4}{2-\cos\theta}$ forms a closed curve. Find the area of the region inside the curve.

Comment: So, where exactly you feel stuck? Do you know how to integrate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Hint

It is an ellipse $4(x^2+y^2)=16+8x+x^2$, and its area is $\pi ab$